# SSIS to copy a Table A from DataBase A to Table A from DataBase B, by deleting the diference from B then inserting the difference from A

Tags: sql-server

I need to copy PROD DB to DEV DB to make tests, I need to do it several times a day.
I tried to a truncate then insert but some tables have almost 60 million rows.

Is there a way of updating only the difference between tables?
I heard this can be done through Slow Changing Dimension.

Basically what I want to do is :

delete from DBDEV the result of this : 
(`SELECT * FROM [DBDEV].[dbo].[TableA] EXCEPT  SELECT * FROM [DBPROD].[dbo].[TableA]`)

Then insert into DBPROD the result of this : 
(`SELECT * FROM [DBPROD].[dbo].[TableA] EXCEPT  SELECT * FROM [DBDEV].[dbo].[TableA]`)

If there's no SSIS component that can help with that, an SQL query would help me, it's just that I don't know how to write it to reflect what I need.

Thank you in advance

Comment: 60 millions rows sounds a lot to be needing in DEV. Is it not a case of create a test database with a small set of data e.g. 1000 rows to cover you dev needs?

Comment: it is for DEV but we give access to users to test DEV too, so they want all the database available.

Comment: Are you looking for table data only?  How many tables?  What about other objects?  (stored procs, udf's, views, users, etc.)

Comment: Yes data only. I imagine, because in our stored procs we specify what DataBase to use, so I imagine that we will just run them from DEV to use PROD data. So I copy the stored procs manually for now